# Use None as initial for itertools.accumulate

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, python-itertools

It'd be nice to use `itertools.accumulate` with `initial=None` to literally mean that it should start with `None`.

For example:

```py
from typing import Optional, Iterable
from itertools import islice, accumulate

def f(a: Optional[A], b: B) -> A:
    pass

b_s: Iterable[B] = [...]
_a_s = accumulate(b_s, f, initial=None)  # doesn't work!
a_s = list(islice(_a_s, 1, None))
```

This fails because `initial=None` tells `accumulate` to use the first element as the initial and go from there, so `f` will end up being called with two `B` arguments.

Does anyone know an easy way around this?
My current plan is to use `False`, but then I have a bunch more hoops to jump through explaining what I'm doing to MyPy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is probably to `chain` the value onto the input iterable:

```
output = accumulate(chain([None], iterable), f)
```